# Regex to validate that first letter of every word is capital in angular js

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation, pattern-matching, ng-pattern

I am using angularjs. I want to use validation for my name field. I am a beginner in regex expressions.
I want that the first letter of every word should be capital. 
For E.g Naveen Kumar should be valid
and Naveen kumar is invalid.

I am using ng-pattern to validate the name field. What regex expression should i use? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please show what you tried?

Comment: I tried to use (\s|^[A-Z])([a-z0-9-_]+).....But it is not working the way i want

Comment: Testing this is not always a good idea, several names with particles may not be valid: "de la Porte", "de la Rue". In my opinion, you should only test your field for allowed characters and if needed, format it before recording it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^\b(?:[A-Z]\w+\b(?:\s*)?)+$
```

See [Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yW8kG6/1)

Comment: Thanks...this is xactly what i needed...works like a charm!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with `ng-pattern`:

```
ng-pattern="/^\b[A-Z][a-z]*(\s*\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)*$/"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR8nT1/3)

This regex will match only entries that have words (that do not contain digits or underscore) in title case only. Thus, `Avinash Raj1` or `Avinash_Raj Raj` will fail the validation.

Example code:

```
<label>Single word:
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="example.text"
           ng-pattern="/^\b[A-Z][a-z]*(\s*\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)*$/" required ng-trim="false">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$`?
See https://regex101.com/r/qP5xG5/1